# Python Unit Testing: Automatically Running the Debugger when a test fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, pdb, python-unittest

Is there a way to automatically start the debugger at the point at which a unittest fails?

Right now I am just using pdb.set_trace() manually, but this is very tedious as I need to add it each time and take it out at the end.

For Example:

```
import unittest

class tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_trigger_pdb(self):
        #this is the way I do it now
        try:
            assert 1==0
        except AssertionError:
            import pdb
            pdb.set_trace()

    def test_no_trigger(self):
        #this is the way I would like to do it:
        a=1
        b=2
        assert a==b
        #magically, pdb would start here
        #so that I could inspect the values of a and b

if __name__=='__main__':
    #In the documentation the unittest.TestCase has a debug() method
    #but I don't understand how to use it
    #A=tests()
    #A.debug(A)

    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import unittest
import sys
import pdb
import functools
import traceback
def debug_on(*exceptions):
    if not exceptions:
        exceptions = (AssertionError, )
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except exceptions:
                info = sys.exc_info()
                traceback.print_exception(*info) 
                pdb.post_mortem(info[2])
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @debug_on()
    def test_trigger_pdb(self):
        assert 1 == 0
```

I corrected the code to call post_mortem on the exception instead of set_trace.

Comment: I'd also advise you to use a global flag to turn this debugging on and off. It would make running tests more complicated. I'd be pretty pissed off if I ran someone's test suite and it popped a debugger.

Comment: Rosh, thanks. It works great. Point well taken about the global flag :)

Comment: This is a nice solution for the moment, so +1.  I would add to your code this:  import pdb; import sys;  and after pdb.post_mortem(...), raise.  This is the rare case when the exception should be re-thrown.  If the user continues a failed test case, it will otherwise be counted as passed.  On another note; if only it were possible to detect pdb already running and not pop up the debugger for unittests, yet break on failures when launched under the debugger, I would be still happier.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: Sounds like there may be a way to detect if the debugger is already running, see question [_How to detect that Python code is being executed through the debugger?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333995/how-to-detect-that-python-code-is-being-executed-through-the-debugger).

Answer (score 37):

I think what you are looking for is [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It works like a test runner for [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html).

You can drop into the debugger on errors, with the following command:

```
nosetests --pdb
```

Comment: If you were to use `self.assertEquals` rather than plain `assert`, so that the test has a "failure" rather than an "error", then the command to run would be `nosetest --pdb-failures`.

Comment: On win32 with python 2.7, I installed nose with `easy_install nose` but then found the command was **nosetests** not nosetest. I also had to run with `--pdb-failures`.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I also find this wonderful command is named '''nosetests''', emphasis on the plural 's' on the end.  One can install the package python-nose (sudo apt-get install python-nose) to have this handy command.  To run an existing test, '''nosetests --pdb-failures ./test_set.py'''  where test_set.py is your existing unit test.

Comment: command is also plural `nosetests` on OSX Mavericks (installed using Enthought Canopy package manager). Maybe answer should be edited?

Nice utility.

Comment: For the sucessor *nose2*, see answer below.

Comment: Downvoted because nose is unmaintained (see nose2).

Comment: You can also use any popular test runner like pytest! It will search for test files by this pattern: *_test.py

Answer (score 4):

A simple option is to just run the tests without result collection and letting the first exception crash down the stack (for arbitrary post mortem handling) by e.g.

```
try: unittest.findTestCases(__main__).debug()
except:
    pdb.post_mortem(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

---

Another option: Override `unittest.TextTestResult`'s `addError` and `addFailure` in a debug test runner for immediate post_mortem debugging (before `tearDown()`) - or for collecting and handling errors & tracebacks in an advanced way.

(Doesn't require extra frameworks or an extra decorator for test methods)

Basic example:

```
import unittest, pdb

class TC(unittest.TestCase):
    def testZeroDiv(self):
        1 / 0

def debugTestRunner(post_mortem=None):
    """unittest runner doing post mortem debugging on failing tests"""
    if post_mortem is None:
        post_mortem = pdb.post_mortem
    class DebugTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):
        def addError(self, test, err):
            # called before tearDown()
            traceback.print_exception(*err)
            post_mortem(err[2])
            super(DebugTestResult, self).addError(test, err)
        def addFailure(self, test, err):
            traceback.print_exception(*err)
            post_mortem(err[2])
            super(DebugTestResult, self).addFailure(test, err)
    return unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=DebugTestResult)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ##unittest.main()
    unittest.main(testRunner=debugTestRunner())
    ##unittest.main(testRunner=debugTestRunner(pywin.debugger.post_mortem))
    ##unittest.findTestCases(__main__).debug()
```

Comment: Does that need to be unittest.findTestCases('__main__').debug() ?

Answer (score 4):

Third party test framework enhancements generally seem to include the feature (`nose` and `nose2` were already mentioned in other answers).  Some more:

[pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#dropping-to-pdb-python-debugger-on-failures) supports it.

```
pytest --pdb
```

Or if you use [absl-py](https://pypi.org/project/absl-py/)'s `absltest` instead of `unittest` module:

```
name_of_test.py --pdb_post_mortem
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply [@cmcginty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012325/1587329) to the successor [***nose 2***](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose2) ([recommended by nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) available on Debian-based systems via `apt-get install nose2`), you can [drop into the debugger](http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/debugger.html) on failures and errors by calling

```
nose2
```

in your test directory.

For this, you need to have a suitable `.unittest.cfg` in your home directory or `unittest.cfg` in the project directory; it needs to contain the lines

```
[debugger]
always-on = True
errors-only = False
```

Comment: `nose2 --debugger` FTW!

Answer (score 0):

To address the comment in your code "In the documentation the unittest.TestCase has a debug() method but I don't understand how to use it", you can do something like this:

```
suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(sys.modules[__name__])
suite.debug()
```

Individual test cases are created like:
`testCase = tests('test_trigger_pdb')` (where `tests` is a sub-class of `TestCase` as per your example). And then you can do `testCase.debug()` to debug one case.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a built-in, no extra modules, solution:

```
import unittest
import sys
import pdb

####################################
def ppdb(e=None):
    """conditional debugging
       use with:  `if ppdb(): pdb.set_trace()` 
    """
    return ppdb.enabled

ppdb.enabled = False
###################################


class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_success(self):
        try:
            pass
        except Exception, e:
            if ppdb(): pdb.set_trace()
            raise

    def test_fail(self):
        try:
            res = 1/0
            #note:  a `nosetests --pdb` run will stop after any exception
            #even one without try/except and ppdb() does not not modify that.
        except Exception, e:
            if ppdb(): pdb.set_trace()
            raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #conditional debugging, but not in nosetests
    if "--pdb" in sys.argv:
        print "pdb requested"
        ppdb.enabled = not sys.argv[0].endswith("nosetests")
        sys.argv.remove("--pdb")

    unittest.main()
```

call it with `python myunittest.py --pdb` and it will halt.  Otherwise it won't.

Answer (score -1):

Some solution above modifies business logic:

```
try:      # <-- new code
 original_code()  # <-- changed (indented)
except Exception as e:  # <-- new code
 pdb.post_mortem(...)   # <-- new code
```

To minimize changes to the original code, we can define a function decorator, and simply decorate the function that's throwing:

```
def pm(func):
    import functools, pdb

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def func2(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            pdb.post_mortem(e.__traceback__)

   raise
    return func2
```

Use:

```
@pm
def test_xxx(...):
 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Buildt a module with a decorator which post mortems into **every type of error except AssertionError**. The decorator can be triggered by the **logging root level**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
Decorator for getting post mortem on errors of a unittest TestCase
'''
import sys
import pdb
import functools
import traceback
import logging
import unittest

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

def debug_on(log_level):
    '''
    Function decorator for post mortem debugging unittest functions.

    Args:
      log_level (int): logging levels coesponding to logging stl module

    Usecase:

    class tests(unittest.TestCase):
        @debug_on(logging.root.level)
        def test_trigger_pdb(self):
            assert 1 == 0
    '''

    def decorator(f):

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except BaseException as err:
                info = sys.exc_info()
                traceback.print_exception(*info)

                if log_level < logging.INFO and type(err) != AssertionError:
                    pdb.post_mortem(info[2])

        return wrapper

    return decorator


class Debug_onTester(unittest.TestCase):

    @debug_on(logging.root.level)
    def test_trigger_pdb(self):
        assert 1 == 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: dif:  Added the functionality that an AssertionError will behave like intendet. Cheers