# how to test a cell with input() value in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, testbook

I want to test jupyter notebooks, with the testbook tool.
It works perfect, until there is a input() to give. How can I mock this?

this is my function in jupyter in the cell 6:

```
a=input('Please enter the first number (a): ')
b=input('Please enter the second number (b): ')
if (a>b):
    print('a is larger than b')
elif (a<b):
    print('b is larger than a')
else:
    print('a equals b')
```

this is my test:

```
@testbook('path', execute=True)
def test_2(tb):  # execute cell tagged "name_checking"
    with tb.patch("ipykernel.kernelbase.Kernel.raw_input") as mock_input:
        mock_input.return_value = [1,1]
        result = tb.execute_cell(6)
        assert tb.cell_output_text(6) == "a equals b"
```

and this is my error:

```
    test.py::test_2 FAILED                                                   [100%]
test.py:12 (test_2)
args = (), kwargs = {}

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  # pragma: no cover
        with self.client.setup_kernel():
>           self._prepare()

..\..\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\testbook\testbook.py:62: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\testbook\testbook.py:46: in _prepare
    self.client.execute()
..\..\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\testbook\client.py:147: in execute
    super().execute_cell(cell, index)
..\..\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\nbclient\util.py:84: in wrapped
    return just_run(coro(*args, **kwargs))
..\..\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\nbclient\util.py:62: in just_run
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:642: in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
..\..\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\nbclient\client.py:965: in async_execute_cell
    await self._check_raise_for_error(cell, cell_index, exec_reply)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <testbook.client.TestbookNotebookClient object at 0x000002B38AF13EB0>
cell = {'cell_type': 'code', 'execution_count': 1, 'metadata': {'execution': {'iopub.status.busy': '2022-05-11T04:25:33.95669...>b):\n    print('a is larger than b')\nelif (a<b):\n    print('b is larger than a')\nelse:\n    print('a equals b')\n"}
cell_index = 6
exec_reply = {'buffers': [], 'content': {'ename': 'StdinNotImplementedError', 'engine_info': {'engine_id': -1, 'engine_uuid': 'c461...e, 'engine': 'c46177df-fc3a-4269-aa23-a1d6902c3c3a', 'started': '2022-05-11T04:25:33.956699Z', 'status': 'error'}, ...}

    async def _check_raise_for_error(
        self, cell: NotebookNode, cell_index: int, exec_reply: t.Optional[t.Dict]
    ) -> None:
    
        if exec_reply is None:
            return None
    
        exec_reply_content = exec_reply['content']
        if exec_reply_content['status'] != 'error':
            return None
    
        cell_allows_errors = (not self.force_raise_errors) and (
            self.allow_errors
            or exec_reply_content.get('ename') in self.allow_error_names
            or "raises-exception" in cell.metadata.get("tags", [])
        )
        await run_hook(self.on_cell_error, cell=cell, cell_index=cell_index)
        if not cell_allows_errors:
>           raise CellExecutionError.from_cell_and_msg(cell, exec_reply_content)
E           nbclient.exceptions.CellExecutionError: An error occurred while executing the following cell:
E           ------------------
E           # Enter your code here!
E           a=input('Please enter the first number (a): ')
E           b=input('Please enter the second number (b): ')
E           if (a>b):
E               print('a is larger than b')
E           elif (a<b):
E               print('b is larger than a')
E           else:
E               print('a equals b')
E           
E           ------------------
E           
E           ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
E           StdinNotImplementedError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
E           Input In [1], in <cell line: 2>()
E                 1 # Enter your code here!
E           ----> 2 a=input('Please enter the first number (a): ')
E                 3 b=input('Please enter the second number (b): ')
E                 4 if (a>b):
E           
E           File ~\Documents\IT-Projekt\pythonProject\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py:1073, in Kernel.raw_input(self, prompt)
E              1066 """Forward raw_input to frontends
E              1067 
E              1068 Raises
E              1069 ------
E              1070 StdinNotImplementedError if active frontend doesn't support stdin.
E              1071 """
E              1072 if not self._allow_stdin:
E           -> 1073     raise StdinNotImplementedError(
E              1074         "raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests."
E              1075     )
E              1076 return self._input_request(
E              1077     str(prompt),
E              1078     self._parent_ident["shell"],
E              1079     self.get_parent("shell"),
E              1080     password=False,
E              1081 )
E           
E           StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests.
E           StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests.

..\..\tickets\venv\lib\site-packages\nbclient\client.py:862: CellExecutionError
```

A similar question was answered in [How to patch input() when testing Jupyter notebook cells with testbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014966/how-to-patch-input-when-testing-jupyter-notebook-cells-with-testbook) but this solution, doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your attempt looks like the OP's example that didn't work. [The solution is below the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69014991/8508004). **"Provide return values from input() using the side_effect argument, not mock_input.return_value"** You tried using `mock_input.return_value`.

Comment: Yes, I also tried the solution but that didn't work either.
@testbook('path', execute=True)
def test(tb):
    with tb.patch(
        "ipykernel.kernelbase.Kernel.raw_input",
        side_effect=[1, 1],
    ) as mock_input:
        tb.execute_cell(6)
        assert tb.cell_output_text(6) == "a equals b"