# Is there a flag I can check in my code to see if PyCharm's debugger is running?

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I'd like to take some actions in my code, conditioned on whether the PyCharm debugger is attached and running — e.g., I've launched my code using the IDE's "Debug" command; something like

```
if pycharm_debugger_is_running:
    do_something()
else:
    do_another_thing()
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Pycharm debugger [has been merged with Pydev's](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#Attach), you may like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26605963/777285).

**Edit**

In order to determine whether the script was launched by Pycharm, I can think of manually adding your own environment variable in the `Run/Debug Configurations`

[image: environ pycharm]

And then check for it:

```
if 'PYCHARM' in os.environ:
    print("running in Pycharm")
```

Actually the most convenient way would probably be to directly edit the default run configuration to automatically integrate that flag in any new run.

[image: default run config pycharm]

Comment: That seems to work! Is there a way to skip that check altogether if I'm running from PyCharm (i.e., is there a way to tell that my code has been launched from PyCharm)?

Comment: I've extended my answer ;)

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

While setting your own environment variable works, I wanted something that was immutable, so there was no chance I could forget to include, or have to add something to every single project configuration. I found that in the modules PyCharm loads.

```
import sys

we_are_in_pycharm = '_pydev_bundle.pydev_log' in sys.modules.keys()

if we_are_in_pycharm:
    print("running in Pycharm")
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question was about a way to check if the script is run with the debugger in pycharm.

Pycharm sets the environment variable PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC when the script is run through the debugger.

To check if the debugger is active you can check if PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC exists in the list of environment variables:

```
import os
if 'PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC' in os.environ:
    print('debugger is running')
else:
    print('normal run')
```

or as a function

```
import os

def debugger_enabled():
    return 'PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC' in os.environ
```

tested in PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Community Edition)

(this is a repost of my original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78118417/1641449 because i found it so practical that i wanted to post it where i searched before but didn't find it.)