# Check if program runs in Debug mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, pycharm

I use the PyCharm IDE for Python programming.

Is there a possibility to check, whether I'm in debugging mode or not when I run my program?

I use pyplot as plt and want a Figure only to be shown if I debug my program. Yes, I could have a global boolean `_debug_` which is set by myself, but I look for a better solution.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the documentation, `settrace` / `gettrace` functions could be used in order to implement Python debugger:

> ```
> sys.settrace(tracefunc)
> ```
>
> Set the system’s trace function, which allows
>   you to implement a Python source code debugger in Python. The function
>   is thread-specific; for a debugger to support multiple threads, it
>   must be registered using `settrace()` for each thread being debugged.

However, these methods may not be available in all implementations:

> **CPython implementation detail**: The `settrace()` function is intended
>   only for implementing debuggers, profilers, coverage tools and the
>   like. Its behavior is part of the implementation platform, rather than
>   part of the language definition, and thus may not be available in all
>   Python implementations.

You could use the following snippet in order to check if someone is debugging your code:

```
import sys


gettrace = getattr(sys, 'gettrace', None)

if gettrace is None:
    print('No sys.gettrace')
elif gettrace():
    print('Hmm, Big Debugger is watching me')
else:
    print("Let's do something interesting")
    print(1 / 0)
```

This one works for pdb:

```
$ python -m pdb main.py 
> /home/soon/Src/Python/main/main.py(3)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb) step
> /home/soon/Src/Python/main/main.py(6)<module>()
-> gettrace = getattr(sys, 'gettrace', None)
(Pdb) step
> /home/soon/Src/Python/main/main.py(8)<module>()
-> if gettrace is None:
(Pdb) step
> /home/soon/Src/Python/main/main.py(10)<module>()
-> elif gettrace():
(Pdb) step
> /home/soon/Src/Python/main/main.py(11)<module>()
-> print('Hmm, Big Debugger is watching me')
(Pdb) step
Hmm, Big Debugger is watching me
--Return--
> /home/soon/Src/Python/main/main.py(11)<module>()->None
-> print('Hmm, Big Debugger is watching me')
```

And PyCharm:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /opt/pycharm-professional/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 34192 --file /home/soon/Src/Python/main/main.py
pydev debugger: process 17250 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.1559)
Hmm, Big Debugger is watching me

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This works in VS Code v1.61.2 debugging as well, including stacked debug sessions (which return the same trace object).

Comment: This work in Pycharm as well

Comment: It seems it doesn't work when you hit continue in the debugger why is that?

Comment: Also why does it divide by 0? What case does that correspond to? That is what happens to me when I hit continue.

Comment: Please show how you run your script, what python version and what debugger do you use. I've just checked with Python 3.9.5 on Mac (pdb) - works just fine. As for `1 / 0` - this is the case when the script is unable to determine debugger.

Comment: @profPlum check my answer - it works if you use continue - none of the other answers work unless you are stepping thru the code

Comment: This does not work in PyCharm for me. Better is RedEyed's solution, which does work in PyCharm for me.

Comment: I've got some false positives with this approach, namely in gitlab pipeline (and I heard pytorch might do something weird with this too). Doing `"pydevd" in sys.modules` worked without false positives for me (in PyCharm, no idea about other IDEs).

Answer (score 24):

The following works for me in VSCode:

```
import sys 

def debugger_is_active() -> bool:
    """Return if the debugger is currently active"""
    return hasattr(sys, 'gettrace') and sys.gettrace() is not None
```

Comment: I like the `lambda: None` option. This always turns the result into a function, so you can resolve it immediately if desired: `trace_object = getattr(sys, 'gettrace', lambda: None)()`. The result will be either the trace object or `None`.

Comment: Why write a function that returns a function that just calls a function.  Why not just ```if sys.gettrace(): do_this()```

Comment: Because sys.gettrace may not be defined for the python enviroment

Comment: Why not the very straight forward: `return hasattr(sys, 'gettrace') and (sys.gettrace() is not None)`?

Comment: Agreed that a logical AND is more intuitive. Answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

Tested on `PyCharm 2021.3.2`:

```py
def is_debug():
    import sys

    gettrace = getattr(sys, 'gettrace', None)

    if gettrace is None:
        return False
    else:
        v = gettrace()
        if v is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a couple alternative implementations.

Using [contextlib.suppress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
import sys 
from contextlib import suppress

def is_debugging() -> bool:
    with suppress(AttributeError):
        return sys.gettrace()
```

Using ["walrus" operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html?highlight=inline%20assignment#assignment-expressions) new since Python 3.8:

```
import sys 

def is_debugging() -> bool:
    return (gettrace := getattr(sys, 'gettrace')) and gettrace()
```

Comment: `(gettrace := getattr(sys, 'gettrace')) and gettrace()`

Answer (score 1):

Adding these three short answer as it seems others are rather long or less to the point.
gettrace() is already a function so no need to write another...

Any of these could (for example) be used to set the logging module logger level.

(tested in Py3.9 with VSCode and PyCharm comtemporary to this post date)

```py
from sys import gettrace
if gettrace():
    print("Debug")
else:
    print("Run")
```

or if you need a variable

```py
import sys
DEBUG = sys.gettrace() is not None
```

or a global - not such a good idea as you risk namespace collisions in large projects.

```py
import sys
sys.modules['GLOB_DEBUG'] = sys.gettrace()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with:

- PyCharm `2020.2` (and many versions before that)
- Python `3.7.5` (and many versions before that)
- `Windows 10 x64`

There are two ways of debugging in PyCharm:

- Method #1: `Selection-Based Debug Mode`: menu `[ View > Tool Windows > Python Console ]`, then select a line, right click then `Execute Selection in Python Console`.
- Method #2: `Standard Debug Mode`: Create a new configuration using `Edit Configuration` on the dropdown in the toolbar, can debug with breakpoints, variable watch, etc.

The function below detects method #1 (above), as it always passes in `--port=XXXX` on the command line.

```
C:\python\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Professional Edition with Anaconda plugin 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=53093
```

Function:

```
import sys

def is_debug_pycharm_by_select():
    """
    Detect if running in Selection-Based Debug Mode under PyCharm:
      -  PyCharm menu [ View > Tool Windows > Python Console ], highlight Python line in editor, right click "Execute Selection in Python Console".
    :return: True if executing selection in Python Console.
    """
    for arg in sys.argv:
        if "--port=" in arg:  # This debug mode passes in "--port=XXXX".
            return True
    return False

if is_debug_pycharm_by_select():
    print("Selection-Based Debug Mode.")
else:
    print("Some other debug mode.")
```

Comment: This seems more hacky and inferior to the other solutions using `gettrace`. Any reason why one would want this instead of `gettrace`?

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm 2021.1.3 with Python 3.9.

Simply used

```
sys.gettrace()
```

Below, debug mood will show the printed 'Now in debug', and run will print the `play Mood`

```
import sys
gettrace= sys.gettrace()

# For debugging
debug_status=True if gettrace else False

def xtest_debug():
    if debug_status:
        print('Now in debug')
    else:
        print('Play Mood')
xtest_debug()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use pycharm, but to check if the program is being debugged using `python -mpdb myFile.py`, this code will work:

```
import sys
if 'pdb' in sys.modules:
    print("I'm being debugged")
```

as long as you don't otherwise `import pdb`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible update for `Python 3.12+` and `PyCharm 2023.3+`:

```py
import sys


def debug_enabled():

    try:
        if sys.gettrace() is not None:
            return True
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        if sys.monitoring.get_tool(sys.monitoring.DEBUGGER_ID) is not None:
            return True
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    return False
```

The context is [PEP 669 – Low Impact Monitoring for CPython](https://peps.python.org/pep-0669/) and [announced support](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#page__content-python-312-and-more) of those features in PyCharm 2023.3. PEP 669 introduced [`sys.monitoring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.monitoring.html) module. And PyCharm may use it instead of `sys.settrace()`. It is indeed so for Debug button, while Python Console still uses `settrace`.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm sets the environment variable PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC when the script is run through the debugger.

To check if the debugger is active you can check if PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC exists in the list of environment variables:

```
import os
if 'PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC' in os.environ:
    print('debugger is running')
else:
    print('normal run')
```

or as a function

```
import os

def debugger_enabled():
    return 'PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC' in os.environ
```

tested in PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Community Edition)

Answer (score -2):

If using Python [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), you could call:

```
logging.root.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)
```

for checking if the root logging level is debug.

Simple as that.