# Check if program runs in Debug mode in PyCharm 2023

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, python-3.12

I use the PyCharm IDE for Python programming. I previously used the methods described in [Check if program runs in Debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634988/) to check whether I'm in debugging mode or not when I run my program.

However, fter the 2023.3 update to PyCharm, those methods stopped working. For example,

```py
sys.gettrace() is None
```

evaluates to `True` regardless of debug mode or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a new solution, which builds on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38637774) by awesoon.

According to the documentation, `settrace` / `gettrace` functions *or the* `breakpointhook` *function* could be used in order to implement a Python debugger:

> ```
> sys.settrace(tracefunc)
> ```
>
> Set the system’s trace function, which allows you to implement a Python source code debugger in Python. The function is
> thread-specific; for a debugger to support multiple threads, it must
> be registered using settrace() for each thread being debugged.

> ```
> sys.breakpointhook()
> ```
>
> This hook function is called by built-in breakpoint(). By default, it
> drops you into the pdb debugger, but it can be set to any other
> function so that you can choose which debugger gets used.

You could use the following snippet in order to check if someone is debugging your code:

```py
import sys
has_trace = hasattr(sys, 'gettrace') and sys.gettrace() is not None
has_breakpoint = sys.breakpointhook.__module__ != "sys"
is_debug = has_trace or has_breakpoint
print(f"{has_trace=} {has_breakpoint=} {is_debug=}")
```

This one works for pdb:

```
PS C:\Users\pvillano> python -m pdb main.py
> c:\users\pvillano\main.py(1)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb) step
> c:\users\pvillano\main.py(2)<module>()
-> has_trace = hasattr(sys, 'gettrace') and sys.gettrace() is not None
(Pdb) step
> c:\users\pvillano\main.py(3)<module>()
-> has_breakpoint = sys.breakpointhook.__module__ != "sys"
(Pdb) step
> c:\users\pvillano\main.py(4)<module>()
-> is_debug = has_trace or has_breakpoint
(Pdb) step
> c:\users\pvillano\main.py(5)<module>()
-> print(f"{has_trace=} {has_breakpoint=} {is_debug=}")
(Pdb) step
has_trace=True has_breakpoint=False is_debug=True
--Return--
> c:\users\pvillano\main.py(5)<module>()->None
-> print(f"{has_trace=} {has_breakpoint=} {is_debug=}")
```

And now it works for PyCharm:

```
C:\Users\pvillano\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\...\Scripts\python.exe -X pycache_prefix=C:\Users\pvillano\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.3\cpython-cache "C:/Users/python/AppData/Local/Programs/PyCharm Professional/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 50772 --file C:\Users\pvillano\main.py 
Connected to pydev debugger (build 233.11799.259)
has_trace=False has_breakpoint=True is_debug=True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It also works for Visual Studio Code

```
PS C:\Users\pvillano>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\pvillano'; & 'C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe' 'c:\Users\pvillano\.vscode-oss\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0-universal\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51165' '--' 'C:\Users\pvillano\main.py'
has_trace=True has_breakpoint=True is_debug=True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not just `PyCharm 2023.3` but also `Python 3.12` implemented [PEP 669 – Low Impact Monitoring for CPython](https://peps.python.org/pep-0669/) with [`sys.monitoring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.monitoring.html) module.

I would suggest the following solution using that new module:

```py
import sys


def debug_enabled():

    try:
        if sys.gettrace() is not None:
            return True
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        if sys.monitoring.get_tool(sys.monitoring.DEBUGGER_ID) is not None:
            return True
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    return False
```