# Catch an exception if no debugger is attached

Tags: python, exception

Is it possible to catch an exception in Python only if a debugger is not attached, and bypass it to the debugger otherwise?

An equivalent C# code:

```csharp
// Entry point
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e) when (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if you are having a Debugger. The question how that is done was awnsered here: [How to detect that Python code is being executed through the debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333995/how-to-detect-that-python-code-is-being-executed-through-the-debugger)

if not you gould pass the error thorug by using raise and the e object.

```py
try:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    if !Debugger.IsAttached:
        MessageBox.Show(e);
    else:
        raise e
```

More on that you could find here: [How to re-raise an exception in nested try/except blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188563/how-to-re-raise-an-exception-in-nested-try-except-blocks)

Comment: Indeed, for some reason I expected the debugger to stop at `raise` instead of the piece of code that throws the exception.